# How Would I Write This In LINQ2SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am slowly porting over an app from MySQL to use Linq2Sql - but one query has stumped me a bit.

> SELECT * FROM Pages WHERE DomainID = @reportid AND (PageContent REGEXP 'display:[  \t]*none') > 0 ORDER BY URL ASC

Any ideas on how I would write something like this with Linq2SQL?  Its the REGEXP bit thats got me stumped?

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, it's looking for a page that contains no "hidden" content (i.e. nothing in the page says `display:none`, with zero or more spaces or tabs between the ':' and the 'none'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use LINQ to return items that match on reportid and that contain 'display:', to minimise the amount of data being returned from the server, and then use regex on client side to filter that list down?

```
var query = Pages.Where( p => p.DomainId == 1 && p.PageContent.IndexOf("display:") > 0).OrderBy( o => o.URL );

var regex = new Regex(@"display\:[\t]*none");

foreach (var page in query)
{
    if( regex.IsMatch(page.PageContent) )
    {
        // Do whatever...                    
    }                    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no way built in to LINQ to SQL, but you have a couple of other choices. The first is to [load your strings in as in-memory objects which you can apply Regex functions to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386867/regex-replace-to-assist-orderby-in-linq/386924#386924). I'm not a big fan of this since it looks like you're potentially getting some very big strings to match against.

The second option is to leverage SQL CLR [as described here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101216022911/http://infinitecodex.com/post/2010/06/05/Use-RegEx-in-SQL-with-CLR-Procs.aspx). This effectively lets you create a stored procedure that gets linked to a CLR method that you create. Whenever you call the method in a LINQ to SQL context, it gets converted to a stored procedure call. Then you use a query like this:

```
var q = from p in context.Pages
        where p.DomainId == reportId && 
              RegExMatch(p.PageContent, "display\:[ \t]*none")
        select p;
```

Comment: +1, if the Regex part is required then a CLR stored proc is probably the way to go.